# How to copy events in KitKat 4.4 Calendar?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, calendar

How do I copy events in KitKat 4.4 Calendar? That possibility to copy events has been removed from the calendar.

Comment: I edited your question to address the issue directly. OTOH, if Google decided to remove the feature consciously, then it's not a bug. Anyway, there's no possibility to know why Google removed that, making the question off-topic (we're not from Google, we're just Android users).

Comment: So...what uh what is the answer? Does anyone even know how to copy events with the current calendar? Or do they know for sure it was removed? I cannot find the answer to either that's why I came here. I mean not being able to do that in ANY calendar app is silly. So I figured it may BE a bug and thus a workaround.

Comment: I couldn't copy an event in the latest Google Calendar on Lollipop too. When I was researching about it yesterday, some suggest to use 3rd-party apps since this feature was removed on KitKat. I'll wait someone to answer if he does have a workaround on KitKat.

Comment: Yeah. Went to Informant based on Pocket Informant I used on my BlackBerry. Nice app.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the only option are third party apps. I found Informant, which is sort of like Pocket Informant (same dev), I used on my blackberry. It seems that stock apps for Android are becoming more and more featureless. I guess "they're" trying to promote using third party apps, I guess, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

- Open Calendar
- Click on List tab
- Find Event to copy, then press on it and hold until a popup window appears
- Choose Copy

Something similar can be done from the Month tab...

- Select the day of the event
- Find Event to copy just below the month calendar
- Press and hold until a popup window appears
- Choose Copy